# redirect selected desktop web link to the mobile site from a mobile phone

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, hyperlink

I am faced with a little challenge. I have a website and also the mobile version. When a user using a mobile phone clicks on a link from another site e.g facebook, i want the user to be redirected to the mobile site displaying the content of the selected link.

Achievement:

i was able to redirect the user from the desktop version to the mobile page.

Challenge

I am unable to display the content of the selected link e.g http://passnownow.com/inblog.php?id=3840#.UToTf3YetfU.twitter.

it only navigates to the mobile site where the user will have to search for the post.

what can i do.

this is my code.

```
<? include("overall.php");?>
<?

session_start();

require_once('mobile_device_detect.php');

$blackberrystatus = mobile_device_detect(true,true,false,true,true,true,true,false,false);

$androidstatus = mobile_device_detect(true,true,true,true,false,true,true,false,false);

$mobile = mobile_device_detect(true,true,true,true,true,true,true,false,false);
$isMobile = (bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od)|android\b.+\bmobile|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry'.
                    '|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.
                    '|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );

if($_GET["view"]=="full"){

    setcookie("passnownow[client]", "pc", $time + 1209600);

    $_SESSION["client"] = "pc";

    }

if ($_GET["ref"]=="android" or $_GET["ref"]=="blackberry"){

    setcookie("passnownow[client]", "app", $time + 1209600);

    $_SESSION["client"] = "app";


    header('location: mobile/new.php?id=""');

    } else if ($_SESSION["client"]=="pc" or $_COOKIE['passnownow']["client"]=="pc"){



        }else if ($mobile or $isMobile){

    setcookie("passnownow[client]", "mobile", $time + 1209600);

    $_SESSION["client"] = "mobile";


    **header('location: mobile/new.php?id=""');**   

        }

    include("overall.php");

?>
```

My question is: how can i pass the `header('location: mobile/new.php?id=""');` to display the selected link e.g `header('location: mobile/new.php?id="234"');`

What code do I add to get the page id of the selected link and pass it to `header('location: mobile/new.php?id=""');`

I tried using the `$_GET['']` command but it didn't work ie `header('location: mobile/new.php?id=<?php $_GET['id']; ?>');`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for your redirect is incorrect and this may be your problem. You're treating the URL variable as a string (ex. `index.php?var="value"`). The proper syntax would be

```
header('Location: mobil/new.php?id=1234');
```

Then when building your string you can do

```
header("Location: mobil/new.php?id={$_GET['id']}");
```

You should always check your inputs for security reasons.

In your last statement

> I tried using the $_GET[''] command but it didn't work ie
>   header('location: mobile/new.php?id=`<?php $_GET['id']; ?>`');

Your problem was that you were trying to enter into PHP when you were already in it. No need to use `<?php` when you haven't closed out of the last opening. Also, though your syntax is already wrong, you were missing an `echo`.